# how to properly mask ssh server background service

Tags: ssh, systemd, services, openssh, sshd

I want to mask ssh so the ssh server is disabled till I need it myself. but still want to have ssh client capabilities.

I use `openssh` and the service is `ssh.service` and its alias `sshd.service`

I use `ubuntu 22.04`

is the correct steps:

```
systemctl stop sshd
systemctl disable sshd
systemctl mask sshd
systemctl mask ssh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and remember to use `sudo`:

```
sudo systemctl stop sshd
sudo systemctl disable sshd
sudo systemctl mask sshd
```

You don't need the 4th line, since `ssh` and `sshd` are aliases.

Comment: did all 4 lines and it worked anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: would the 4th line cause any problems?

Comment: No, but it does the same as line 3.